# What is the Correct Name of these data Structures? (Tabular or Metadata)

Tags: database, data-warehouse

Usually I use this data structure to store information in my DWH Fact Tables

[image]

Every month we have requests to add more metrics and dimensions to this fact table so as the number of entries increases this becomes more complex.

I was wondering to migrate this structures to another kind of data structure, something like this:

[image]

So I do not have to change my tables structure and delegate the metric calculations to the business layer.

*Do anyone know what is the canonical name of these structures? So that I can start looking for documentation.*

Plus, if someone know the disadvantages of using this...

Comment: Your proposed design is commonly called an EAV (entity-attribute-value) table. It's generally considered an anti-pattern, so study it and think carefully before implementing. I suggest you search StackOverflow and the web with that term for discussion of advantages/disadvantages.

Comment: Thanks a lot @reaanb :)